# Zeroing and returning data in cells using the checkbox does not return old values (resulting in empty fields)

Tags: excel, vba

After unchecking the checkbox, the fields are empty, the old value is not returned.
I was trying to create an ActiveX checkbox that, when clicked, would hide all fields located relative to the value being searched for, as well as reset the numeric field to zero, and then when unchecked would return everything as it was. As I understand it, I am storing the data of the cell to be zeroed incorrectly. Please help me.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim targetValue As String
    Dim originalColor As Long
    Dim originalInteriorColor As Long
    Dim originalValue As Variant
    
    targetValue = "СОК"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Текущее состояние") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ' When the checkbox is checked, change the text and background color of matching cells to white
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:AE61")
            If cell.Value = targetValue Then
                originalColor = cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color
                originalInteriorColor = cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color of the cell on the left to white
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                
                ' Store the original value of cell.Offset(0, -2)
                originalValue = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
             
                
                ' Set the value of cell.Offset(0, -2) to zero
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 0
            End If
        Next cell
    Else
        ' When the checkbox is unchecked, reset the text and background color to the original for matching cells
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:AE61")
            If cell.Value = targetValue Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Reset background color to original
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Reset background color to original
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Reset background color to original
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(152, 212, 84)
                
                ' Restore the original value to cell.Offset(0, -2)
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = originalValue
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want variable values to persist between runs, you need to store them in a global variable, or declare them as `Static` in the Sub   Also - you're looping over many cells, but only storing the "original" settings for the last-matched cell.

Comment: You're storing the original value and color information for the first cell that matches targetValue, and then  trying to restore all cells to this same value and color.  I would use a collection to store the original values and colors for each matching cell.

Comment: `cell.Offset(0,-3).Resize(1,4).Font.Color = vbWhite` etc No need to change each cell individually.

Comment: And how to use collection to store values data?